# Hypersurfaces containing a fixed linear subspace

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am actually trying to solve an exercise about cubic hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ containing a fixed linear subspace of dimension $k-1$. This exercice come from D . Huybrechts'notes ([http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~huybrech/Notes.pdf](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/%7Ehuybrech/Notes.pdf) , exercise 1.5.2 page 65) and I cannot figure out the  result of the second question.

First question is : 1) Let $P$ be a fixed linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}^{n+1}$ of dimension $k-1$. Compute the dimension of the linear system of cubic hypersurfaces of dimension $n$ containing P.
Using the short exact sequence defining the structure sheaf of $P$ and tensoring by $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n+1}}(3)$ one finds $$\vert I_P \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n+1}}(3)\vert=\binom{n+4}{3}-\binom{k+2}{3}-1$$
Then and it is the second question, we have to conclude that the dimension of the moduli space of smooth cubic hypersurfaces of dimension $n$ ( denoted by $\mathcal{M}_n$) verify : $$dim \  \mathcal{M}_n > dim \vert I_P \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n+1}}(3)\vert \Leftrightarrow \binom{k+2}{3} >n+2 $$
The moduli space of such hypersurfaces is given by $H^0(\mathbb{P}^{n+1},\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n+1}}(3))$ quotiented by the group $GL_{n+2}$. Thus I find as a condition $\binom{k+2}{3} > (n+2)^2-1$ which seems to be wrong. Any help would be welcome to explain me where my reasonment is false. Thank you by advance